# Why do I only get 'Python' when I try to check my Python version?

Tags: python

so I've installed Python in my desktop, and tried to figure out the version. So in the command prompt, I typed `python --version`. But I got `Python` and that's it. What have I done wrong? Below is the demonstration.

```
C:\Users\ryanoh>python --version
Python
```

I've tried the same thing in the directory where Python is installed, but it gives exactly the same result. Just as below.

```
C:\Users\ryano\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.9>python --version
Python
``
```

Comment: Where did you download the Python installer from? You seem to be using an unofficial build.

Comment: Those are the first characters of the expected output.  Maybe the output us being truncated at the first space for some unknown reason.

Comment: Strange. How did you install Python? Does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version_info)"` print the expected values? How about `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The command you recommended also gives ```Python```. Maybe I should try reinstalling python :(

Comment: @RyanOh which one? Only the second one, right? What does `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version_info)"` give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh hey I tried reinstalling Python and now it works. That was really strange. Thanks by the way! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same problem, although I can not remember explicitly installing Python.

I suspected that I should have a copy of an interpreter when I've installed Visual Studio with Python workload. It turns out I don't have Visual Studio, but Visual Studio Code.

When I've ran `python --version` in the command line I got no error and the only output was the word "Python". I've searched in My Computer for the "python" string and got nothing.

I also tried a script with the following commands:

```
import sys 
print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
print("Version info.") 
print (sys.version_info)
```

But I got the same output.

My conclusion is that I simply don't have Python installed or there is some let say pseudo Python stub in the OS I am using.

I am using Windows 10 Home edition.

Hope this helps.